# Insert many in mongoose not save the document with the default value in the scheme

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I set a parameter that is not required in model on mongoose and has a default value, that I use insert many of documents into the same collection, it saves the document without the parameter I set that is not required with the default value that i set in the schema. This means that the parameter does not exist.

```
const paymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userId: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    required: false,
},
amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
},
identifier: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,})
```

when i save this document like this:

```
await PaymentDB.insertMany(req.body.payments);
```

in mongodb i don't see the status parameter , why?

Comment: Hi! And `PaymentDB` in this case is the model, right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: I've just checked my old code and I see that I had to set default values manually, because my array was really huge. But if you have "normal size" array to insert and it wont cause performance issues for you - try Model.create method instead of Model.insertMany.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce your issue with `.insertMany`. And my inserted records have default field added. Let me check one more thing and I'll get back to you

Comment: Can you post your whole model and show how PaymentDB is defined in your case?
It's working for me and I doubt that it's because of different mongoose version.